# How to combine and simplify the following functions?

Tags: c#

I have number of functions that have mostly similar implementations:

```
private async void buttonSetQmBrakeDelay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects.Cast<QMDevice>().ToList();
    if (cells == null)
        return;

    await Task.WhenAll(cells.Select(async c =>
    {
        bool b = await c.SetBrakeDelay((uint)numericUpDownQmBrakeDelay.Value);
        ...
    }));
}

private async void buttonPsMoveTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cells = objectListView.CheckedObjects.Cast<PSDevice>().ToList();
    if (cells == null)
        return;

    await Task.WhenAll(cells.Select(async c =>
    {
        bool b = await c.MoveTo((float)numericUpDownPsTargetPos.Value, (float)numericUpDownPsSpeedOverride.Value);
        ...
    }));
}
```

The only difference is the Cast type and body of anonymous function. How can I create a single method, where I pass the type and anonymous function?

I expect something like this:

```
private async void buttonPsMoveTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CheckAndRunCommandAsync(PSDevice, {
        bool b = await c.SetBrakeDelay((uint)numericUpDownQmBrakeDelay.Value);
    ...
    });
}
```

Comment: How about removing dead code? Like that if-statement, `.ToList()` won't return `null` so you can remove that.

Comment: Half of your repeated code is just redundant, and can be removed.  Once  you do that you're only left with *one* property access and *one* method call as "redundant" code.  You'd end up with more redundant code trying to refactor that out than just leaving it in there.  Different methods will sometimes call the same other method, that isn't a problem to try to solve.

Comment: Also, does this code work? I ask because you use `Cast`, are you sure you didn't mean `OfType`?

Comment: You can't with the click method.  Instead create a third generic method that you call from the two other click methods.  the third method contains the common code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: yes, this code works just fine. Just I have too many of those buttons calls with similar code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What's wrong with `Cast`?  It's a perfectly appropriate thing to do if you know the objects will be of the appropriate type.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just found it odd that all the objects are **both** `PSDevice` and `QMDevice`. If they are in fact the same type I would probably look for ways to reduce those methods down to 1 that doesn't know about either type but use some common interface.

Comment: Either way, you can probably factor everything out into a common method that takes the collection + `Action<T>`, and passes each element to the action. Not sure it saves you much though since, as I said, you can already remove some of the code that is unnecessary, and what you have left is probably not much more than what you're going to have left in each method anyway.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I expect to have

Comment: @Pablo And what problems did you have writing that method?

Comment: Try `void CheckAndRunCommandAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> func) { ... }`.

Comment: @Servy: Just not clear how to deal with syntax.

Comment: @Pablo What did you try, what happened when you tried it, what works, and what doesn't work, what research did you do on how to solve the problems that you couldn't solve, and how did that fail to produce a solution for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're describing can be written like this:

```
private async Task CastAndApplyCheckedObjects<T>(Func<T, Task> command)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(objectListView.CheckedObjects.Cast<T>().Select(command));
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
private async void buttonPsMoveTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CastAndApplyCheckedObjects<PSDevice>(async c => {
        bool b = await c.SetBrakeDelay((uint)numericUpDownQmBrakeDelay.Value);
    ...
    });
}
```

As people have mentioned in the comments, I don't really see a point in using `Cast`. If you already have a guarantee that all items will be the type you want, then why isn't `CheckedObjects` a collection of that type? If you don't have that guarantee, you should probably be using `OfType` or otherwise the cast could throw an exception.

Comment: exactly what I was after. But not sure how I remove Cast in your function. `CheckedObjects` is returning `IList`. It's from ObjectListview framework. I do know that CheckedObjects is returning the type that I want.

Comment: @Pablo If `CheckedObjects`' declared type is something that's beyond your control, and you're sure they're the right type, then I think you can stick with the `Cast`.